# Mouse problem in draftsight

Tags: cad, mouse-pointer

I have installed draftsight (CAD alternative app to Autodesk one) for Ubuntu but I am not able to use the mouse in the model space.

The "arrow" is moving slowly and delayded than in other applications and than the other part of the application (menu, labels).

The problem can be that the app is a beta version?

Answer (score 0):

I have learned of a partial solution from youtube comments and a few other locations. Assuming you are using a USB mouse unplug the mouse, start Draftsight, the plug the mouse in. The mouse wheel doesn't seem to work so zoomiing is a pain but the cursor is at least usable. 
[Z] [Enter] [E] [Enter] to zoom to the limits of the drawing
[Z] [Enter] [W] [Enter] to draw a zoom window